# .htaccess rewrite wildcard folder paths from host

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

My desired result is change a file to root `/` from a N number of paths.

For example: `www.host.com/a/b/c/e/f/g/images/1.jpg`, where `A~G` is not always given. Result: `www.host.com/images/1.jpg`.

This is what I have so far: `www.host.com/a/images`  --> `www.host.com/images` using: `RewriteRule ^a\/images/$ images/$1 [L]`.

What I need is a wildcard in front of `/images/` like this: `RewriteRule ^*\/images/$ images/$1 [L]`.

How can I do this correctly in *.htaccess*?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^a\/images/$ images/$1 [L]
> ```

There is no capturing group in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, so the `$1` backreference is always empty and will only rewrite the request from `/a/images/` to `/images/` (note the trailing slash).

To rewrite a request to *any* path depth then you simply need to establish that there is *something* (even just 1 character) in the URL-path before `/images/` in the requested URL.

Taking the above points into consideration you could do something like the following:

```
RewriteRule ./(images/.*) $1 [L]
```

The `$1` backreference contains everything that we want to rewrite the request to. ie. `images/<anything>`.

The above would internally rewrite a request for `/a/b/c/e/f/g/images/<anything>` to `/images/<anything>`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick: `RewriteRule ^.+\/images/$ images/$1 [L]`

In regex, the `.+` is a wildcard matching at least one character, so it will match

`www.host.com/**a**/images` and `www.host.com/**a/b**/images` but **not** `www.host.com/images`.

When working with regular expressions for pattern matching, I have always found this page helpful: http://regular-expressions.info/.

Comment: This only matches `.../images/` - it does not match the filename. And since there is no capturing group in the `RewriteRule` _pattern_, the `$1` backreference in the _substitution_ string is always empty.